# GETTING SERIALIZING ERROR WHILE ASSIGNING VALUE TO THE DFDL PARSER IN ESQL

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker, dfdl

Getting Serializing error

IIB 9 and Websphere MQ

I have a sample message flow. with MQInput node, Compute node, Mqoutput node and using DFDL.

I have a dfdl with one mandatory segment and other 3 are non mandatory segments.

in non mandatory segments i have this type of tree structure.

ROOT 
    SEGMENT 1
        ELEMENT1
        ELEMENT2
        ELEMENT3
        ELEMENT4
        ELEMENT5
    SEGMENT 2
        ELEMENT1
        ELEMENT2
        ELEMENT3
        ELEMENT4
    SEGMENT 2
        ELEMENT1
        ELEMENT2
        ELEMENT3
        ELEMENT4

CONSIDER second SEGMENT2 >> ELEMENT2 is not populating. If I want to add ELEMENT2 in the ESQL using ESQL i am getting serializing error.

---

CASE  : I can assign value for ELEMENT2 by creating field as NEXSIBLING for ELEMENT1 .

### CREATE NEXTSIBLING OF REF_SEGMENT TYPE Name NAMESPACE NS NAME 'NAME OF THE FIELD';

Here i am creating next sibling of ELEMENT1 so i can create ELEMENT2 so that i can assign values to the ELEMENT 2 . but problem i am facing when ELEMENT 1 and ELEMENT 3 is null then

I couldn't create the ELEMENT2 as NEXTSIBLING or PREVIOUSSIBLING.

we have CREATE FIELD function but it is adding element at the END of the logical tree structure. so that try also failing.

**CREATE FIELD OutputRoot.XMLNS.TestCase.description TYPE NameValue VALUE 'This is my TestCase';**

Note : no option to change DFDL we are using same dfdl for other interfaces. only way is ESQL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming ELEMENT1 and ELEMENT2 are 2 different fields with those names.
In that case you should be able to do either of the following to create ELEMENT2 even when ELEMENT1 is not created first:

- SET OutputRoot.DFDL.ROOT.SEGMENT2[2].ELEMENT2 = 'test';
- CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot.DFDL.ROOT.SEGMENT2[2] NAME 'ELEMENT2' VALUE 'test';

SEGMENT1 and the first SEGMENT2 (OutputRoot.DFDL.ROOT.SEGMENT2[1]) must be created before though.